# Executing cross-compiled C++ program using Boost on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, boost, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I have built a GCC cross toolchain for the RPi and can cross-compile C++ source and successfully run it after copying the executable to the RPi.

Next I built the Boost libraries targeting ARM, using the cross toolchain. I can successfully build and link C++ source to those Boost libraries using the cross toolchain on my PC.

I then copied the program, dynamically linked to Boost, to the RPi and copied all built libraries into `/usr/local/lib` on the Pi. However, executing fails:

```
$ ./my_program
./my_program: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.60.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Again, this library, `libboost_system.so.1.60.0`, exists in `/usr/local/lib`.
I also tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/lib'
```

but that doesn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT:

I build all source files like this (`rpi-g++` is a symlink to my cross-compiler):

```
rpi-g++ -c -std=c++1y -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -I /path/to/cross/boost/include *.cpp
rpi-g++ -o myprog *.o -L /path/to/cross/boost/lib/ -lboost_system -pthread
```

### EDIT 2:

When linked with

```
rpi-g++ -o myprog *.o -L /path/to/cross/boost/lib/ -rdynamic -lboost_system -pthread
```

the problem remains the same. I have checked and verified everything suggested by Technaton as well. Strangely, `ldd` **insists that the created executable is** "`not a dynamic executable`" (checked that on my PC and on the RPi), which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

There are several things you can check. I've posted a complete check list here, but judging from your linker command line, *number 5* is probably the culprit.

1. Check that your library and your program are correctly build for the target architecture. You can verify that by using `file ./myprog` and `file libboost_system.so.1.60.0`.
2. Make sure that you have copied the actual shared object, and not a link to it.
3. Ensure that the shared object file's permissions are sane (0755).
4. Run `ldconfig -v` and check that your shared object file is picked up. Normally, `/usr/local/lib` is in the standard library search path, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not required.
5. Make sure that your program is actually dynamically linked by running `ldd ./myprog`. Judging from your linker command line, that is the problem: You're missing `-rdynamic`.
6. Check the paths returned from `ldd`: If you have linked with rpath, the library search path might be screwed up. Try again without `-rpath`.

Comment: `ldconfig` definately picks it up, I see it in the output. The exec bit is set, and I used `chown` and `chgrp` to ensure that the user could access it. It does not change anything, sadly. Same error.

Comment: What's the output of `file libboost_system.so.1.60.0`?

Comment: `libboost_system.so.1.60.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`. I already checked that and assumed it to be correct, but I could be wrong. It is 'installed' into a subdirectory of my home folder (on my PC), I direct the linker there using `-L` when cross-building.

Comment: Yes, the linker would bail out if the library wasn't match, architecture-wise. What happens if you run `ldd ./myprog`, with and without having `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set? (`/usr/local/lib` doesn't normally require you to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but one can never be sure...) Additionally, check if your program was linked with the rpath option, which might lead the Linux on the Pi to look for the shared object file in the wrong location. The output of `ldd` should make that apparent.

Comment: This seems to be problematic. `ldd ./myprog` gives `not a dynamic executable`... but `file` (as run on the RPi) says `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 4.1.13, not stripped`. What sorcery is this?

Comment: Please post your linker command line when building `myprog` (the best would be adding to your question).

Comment: You are probably missing `-rdynamic` to your linker command line. I'll update my answer and delete our discussion. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101132/discussion-between-discobarmolokai-and-technaton).